# Reopen NSF Fastlane question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The following question was closed as off-topic.

- [NSF fastlane removes hyperref links from PDFs when fontspec is used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/381071/2693)

I really don't think this question  should have been closed. We have other questions e.g. dealing problems with uploading to arXiv which are considered on-topic. We don't know for sure that the problem is simply one of the fact that NSF redistills the uploaded PDF.  NSF receives thousands of submissions and many users use LaTeX, so there might be a real solution out there but closing the question will prevent any new answer.

This is not the type of off-topic question that will attract lots of irrelevant answers, so I think that leaving it open has more potential benefits than closing it.

Comment: However the problem seems to be solved by the OP by reading the NSF manual, isn't that also a reason to close?

Comment: @Marijn I'm not convinced, but I don't have time to investigate it more at the moment.

Comment: @Marijn - The NSF manual only _partially_ solved the problem.  I'm still left with the overall problem of hyperlinks being broken.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Rare case of being of the same opinition ;-) Voted to Reopen

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is becoming a habit. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn: Don't underestimate our differences ;-)

Comment: I don't think it should be closed because it might be on-topic. It might not, but that's not known. People tend to close questions on the grounds we probably can't answer them, but I don't think that is usually a good reason. (I didn't know the question was closed.)

Comment: I stand by my comment: "You are asking us about some online service that does stuff to PDFs. Ask the purveyors of that service, not us."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question has now been successfully reopened.

Comment: Did your question really need an answer? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I'm a sucker for meta rep.

Comment: @AlanMunn You do know that that's not a thing, don't you?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I have 131k reputation on the main site. What are the chances that I don't?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Meta has tag badges though ;-)